# Add a section before \tableofcontents to content

Tags: table-of-contents

Hi I want to add the section of Signature, which is before \tableofcontents, to the Content. Don't know why my codes don't work. Is it even possible? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, right=1.25in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.75in, headsep=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,indentfirst,setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Test}
\author{ABC}
\date{\today}
\maketitle



\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}

\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Signature Page}


\begin{center}
\vspace{.25in}

Signature

\end{center}





\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents



\mainmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Inference}

\section{Introduction}


\backmatter

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{ims}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{mybibliography}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are using `Chapter` instead of `chapter` in the line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Signature Page}
```

I would also eliminate `\numberline` from that line. Note also that you need to add a `\phantomsection` to let `hyperref` point to the right page.

Substituting it with

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Signature Page}
```

you get

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, right=1.25in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.75in, headsep=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,indentfirst,setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Test}
\author{ABC}
\date{\today}
\maketitle



\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Signature Page}


\begin{center}
\vspace{.25in}

Signature

\end{center}





\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents



\mainmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Inference}

\section{Introduction}


\backmatter

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{ims}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
%\bibliography{mybibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pittance. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a `chapter` entry to the ToC, not a `Chapter` entry. That is, you need to use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Signature Page}
```

and *not*

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Signature Page}
```

The former executes `\l@chapter` when it processes the ToC, while the latter requests some macro `\l@Chapter` which does not exist.

Yes, (La)TeX is case-sensitive when it comes to control sequences.