# Force adding certain page on the TOC without using \chapter* command

Tags: table-of-contents, book-class

I want to include my cover page in the table of contents. Since, i'm not using `\chapter{...}` or `\chapter*{...}` to write the title. The reason is i put image logo on the top, so i won't use `\chapter*{...}`. But i  don't know how to add this page in the TOC.

Maybe there is something like :

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{page 1}{`covername`} ?
```

Please help and thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a section before \tableofcontents to content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243761/add-a-section-before-tableofcontents-to-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is at [Add a section before \tableofcontents to content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243761/add-a-section-before-tableofcontents-to-content)

add

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{covername}
```

on the cover page.